# Is there any rsync parameter for show at the end the changes made?

Tags: rsync

I have a script that sync (mirror mode) four folders between two disks. While it is running it shows the directory where it is in this very moment, and at the end it shows bytes sent, speed, etc.

I'm wondering if there is a parameter that shows the changes made at the end. For example:

- Copied a,b,c from A/asd to B/asd
- Deleted d,e,f from B/asd

Comment: Are you looking for `rsync -v`?

Comment: In theory yes, I'm using -av --delete. However it lists files and directories even if they haven't had any change.

Comment: That's not expected behavior. I just tested using rsync 3.0.7, and it did not do that.

Comment: probably an timestamp issue. Try to rsync with `-c` Option. Does it still copy excess files?

Comment: I've been trying out and indeed, it says when copy or delete a file. However, why when my script runs it says that some files were copied, even if they aren't modified for more than a year? The -c disable a very important check as is the last modify, so I won't use it.

Answer (score 0):

The option `-i` or `--itemize-changes` will output a line for each file transferred or deleted, with codes describing the file type and the condition that made it decide to transfer that particular file.

For example, a line may look like

```
>f.st.... cd64.iso
```

Here, `>` means transferred to the local system from a remote system.  The `f` indicates a regular file, and the `s` and the `t` shows me that the file was transferred because both its size and last modification time was different on the remote system compared to on my local machine.

The format is described in detail in the `rsync` manual (look for `--itemize-changes`).